# How do I merge hashes from an array of hashes

Tags: perl

Input array:

```
my @input = (
    {
        Id => 1,
        A => "abcd",
        B => undef,
        C => "rtyt"
    },
    {
        Id => 1, 
        A => undef,
        B => "efgh", 
    },
    {
        Id => 2,
        A => "ifk",
        B => "rjot",
    },
);
```

Desired output:

```
my @output = (
    {
        Id => 1,
        A => "abcd",
        B => "efgh",
        C => "rtyt"
    },
    {
        Id => 2,
        A => "ifk",
        B => "rjot",
    },
);
```

Other solutions I've seen here either include the extra values from first hash or from second hash, but I need both.

Comment: Grouping hashes into arrays with same Id, and then `reduce()`(https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#reduce) into single hash looks straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashes are great for grouping things.

```perl
# Keep first value in case of conflict.
my %by_id;
for my $rec (@input) {
   my $id = $rec->{Id};
   for my $k (keys(%$rec)) {
      $by_id{$id}{$k} //= $rec->{$k};
   }
}
```

or

```perl
# Keep last value in case of conflict.
my %by_id;
for my $rec (@input) {
   my $id = $rec->{Id};
   $by_id{$id} //= { %$rec };
   for my $k (keys(%$rec)) {
      if (defined($rec->{$k})) {
         $by_id{$id}{$k} = $rec->{$k};
      }
   }
}
```

The above builds

```perl
my %by_id = (
    "1" => {
        Id => 1,
        A => "abcd",
        B => "efgh",
        C => "rtyt",
    },
    "2" => {
        Id => 2,
        A => "ifk",
        B => "rjot",
    },
);
```

Then, we can simply extract the values.

```perl
my @output = @by_id{
   sort { $a <=> $b }
      keys(%by_id)
};
```

Comment: It says Error: Global symbol "%rec" requires explicit package name at line "if (defined($rec{$k})) {".

Comment: Weird, I didn't get a notification for the OP's comment. @TLP, Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. Just one more question if you have the time. Let's say I have `D => undef` in both the hashes with Ids '1', is there any way to to retain that `D => undef` in `@output` ? Because right now that is getting removed.

Comment: Updated. Does it matter which value is kept in case of conflict?